# How to sum properties of objects from array and store it to parent object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, sum

I have an array of objects, for example:

```
var obj = {
   "ABC" : {
      "name" : "ABC",
      "budget" : 0,
      "expense" : 0,
      "ledgers" : [{
        "Actual1920": 10,
       "Budget1920": 20,
      },
      {
       "Actual1920": 10,
       "Budget1920": 10,
      }]
  },
  "PQR" : {
    "name" : "PQR",
    "budget" : 0,
    "expense" : 0,
    "ledgers" : [{
      "Actual1920": 10,
      "Budget1920": 20,
    }]
  }
}
```

I want to sum Actual1920 which is in ABC object and it's Ledgers array and store it ABC's budget and same for expense

**Expected Result**

```
var obj = {
   "ABC" : {
      "name" : "ABC",
      "budget" : 30,
      "expense" : 20,
      "ledgers" : [{
        "Actual1920": 10,
       "Budget1920": 20,
      },
      {
       "Actual1920": 10,
       "Budget1920": 10,
      }]
  },
  "PQR" : {
    "name" : "PQR",
    "budget" : 20,
    "expense" : 10,
    "ledgers" : [{
      "Actual1920": 10,
      "Budget1920": 20,
    }]
  }
}
```

Store sum of Actual1920 to expense and Budget1920 to budget.

Comment: You should add the code you've attempted to solve your problem as a [mcve] in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the sum of your required field new array name `ledgers` using `forEach()`, `.map()` function .

```
var arr =  [  {
    "name": "Salary",
    "budget": 0,
    "expense": 0,
    "remaing": 0,
    "ledgers": [
    {
    "Actual1920": 9009006,
    "Budget1920": 46861141.9709555,
    "CostOwner": "Lakshmi Mohan",
    "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
    "LedgerBudget": "Salary",
    "LedgereType": "Salary-Teaching",
    "RemainingAmount": 37852135.9709555,
    "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA",
    "quaterFour": 11715285.492738875,
    "quaterOne": 11715285.492738875,
    "quaterThree": 11715285.492738875,
    "quaterTwo": 11715285.492738875
    },
    {
    "Actual1920": 7765368,
    "Budget1920": 33788679.599044524,
    "CostOwner": "Lakshmi Mohan",
    "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
    "LedgerBudget": "Salary",
    "LedgereType": "Salary-Non Teaching",
    "RemainingAmount": 26023311.599044524,
    "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA",
    "quaterFour": 8447169.899761131,
    "quaterOne": 8447169.899761131,
    "quaterThree": 8447169.899761131,
    "quaterTwo": 8447169.899761131
    },
    {
    "Actual1920": 0,
    "Budget1920": 0,
    "CostOwner": "Lakshmi Mohan",
    "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
    "LedgerBudget": "Salary",
    "LedgereType": "Salary-Contract & Professional",
    "RemainingAmount": 0,
    "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA",
    "quaterFour": 0,
    "quaterOne": 0,
    "quaterThree": 0,
    "quaterTwo": 0
    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "name": "Scholarship & Discounts",
    "budget": 0,
    "expense": 0,
    "remaing": 0,
    "ledgers": [
    {
    "Actual1920": 1460000,
    "Budget1920": 15977747.5,
    "CostOwner": "Vineeta S",
    "LTRevExp": "Expense-EB",
    "LedgerBudget": "Scholarship & Discounts",
    "LedgereType": "Scholarship & Discount",
    "RemainingAmount": 14517747.5,
    "leadgerLevel": "EBITDA",
    "quaterFour": 0,
    "quaterOne": 3723000,
    "quaterThree": 12254747.5,
    "quaterTwo": 0
    }
    ]
    }
   ]

var ledger = {"salary" : 0 , "Expense" : 0 , "remaining" : 0};
arr.forEach(function(singleObject){
    singleObject.ledgers.forEach(function(singleArrObject){
        Object.keys(singleArrObject).map((o)=>{
            if(o == "Actual1920"){

                ledger.salary = ledger.salary + singleArrObject[o]; 
            }
            else if(o == "Budget1920"){
                ledger.Expense = ledger.Expense + singleArrObject[o];
            }
            else if(o == "RemainingAmount"){
                ledger.remaining = ledger.remaining + singleArrObject[o];
            }
        })
    })
});
console.log(ledger);
```

Comment: It returns 0 in all the Objects

Comment: Copy my code and run it in your browser's console . It will give you your wanted output . @ViralPatel

Comment: Check it out and lemme know if you face any problem . @ViralPatel

Comment: I want sum in the same Object not in new. I updated question

Comment: In same object ? Didn't get cleared with that . Will you please explain it in more detail sir . @ViralPatel

Comment: Thanks, it Works! I just need to change ledger.remaining to singleObject.remaining

Comment: Please accept the answer and upvote it . Thank you . Happy to help you . @ViralPatel

Answer (score 0):

```
    arr.forEach(function(singleObject){
       console.log(singleObject);
       singleObject.ledgers.forEach(function(singleArrObject){
        Object.keys(singleArrObject).map((o)=>{
            if(o == "Actual1920"){

                singleObject.expense = singleObject.expense + singleArrObject[o]; 
            }
            else if(o == "Budget1920"){
                singleObject.budget = singleObject.budget + singleArrObject[o];
            }
            else if(o == "RemainingAmount"){
                singleObject.remaining = singleObject.remaining + singleArrObject[o];
            }
        })
    })
});
```